# Where can I find the history of a user's activity?

Tags: support, questions, users

Can we see the list of questions that we have asked before on Stack Overflow? If so where do we find those details? I mean the history of the activities that the user has had.

Answer (score 1):

They all exist on the user profile page.

Just click the link that is the user display name, wherever that is.

You will see tabs for questions, answers and other activities.